# What type of semantics is used in Perl?

Tags: perl, semantics, formal-semantics, denotational-semantics

I am doing a project about Perl and I would like to know which type of semantics does it use (Denotational, Operational, or Axiomatic) but I can not find it anywhere. Any idea which kind does Perl use?
Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Formal semantics are a computer science thing, and are largely irrelevant in the context of real-world language implementations. For Perl 5, the *behaviour* of the `perl` program defines the Perl language. There is no specification or formal description of the semantics. If you really have to press Perl into your categories, then it might be possible to say that Perl is defined via operational semantics encoded in the `perl` interpreter.

Comment: I am making a computer science project so that is why I was interested to know that, thank you! :)